# Ubuntu 17.04 Nvidia Drivers 375

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am trying to install Nvidia drivers on my GTX 1080 on Ubuntu 17.04. This is the method I am using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
```

**NOTE**: *Safe-boot **off** on BIOS*

However, after restarting it goes to a black screen with the following lines:

```
[ ok ] Started User Manager for UID 120
Stopping User Manager for UID 120...
```

After that nothing else happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using lightdm?

Comment: GDM, I am using Ubuntu gnome

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I have the same error...